# How to display Tooltip without hovering pie chart with Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, adminlte

[image]

I'm using AdminLTE and chart.js for pie charts. The question is, can i make the text visible for each arc in the pie chart without hovering mouse?
I don't use legends because some chart have a lot of labels in it.

If you have any other ways to show the all text labels i would appreciate it.

This is my current script for all my pie charts

```
<script>    
                $(function () {
                    //-------------
                    //- PIE CHART -
                    //-------------
                    // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
                    var pieChartCanvas = $('#pieChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
                    var pieChart       = new Chart(pieChartCanvas)
                    var PieData        = [<?php echo $isiData; ?>]

                    var pieOptions     = {                      
                    //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
                    segmentShowStroke    : true,
                    //String - The colour of each segment stroke
                    segmentStrokeColor   : '#fff',
                    //Number - The width of each segment stroke
                    segmentStrokeWidth   : 2,
                    //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
                    percentageInnerCutout: 0, // This is 0 for Pie charts
                    //Number - Amount of animation steps
                    animationSteps       : 150,
                    //String - Animation easing effect
                    animationEasing      : 'easeOutBack',
                    //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
                    animateRotate        : true,
                    //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
                    animateScale         : false,
                    //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
                    responsive           : true,
                    // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
                    maintainAspectRatio  : true,

                    //String - A legend template
                    legendTemplate       : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
                    }

                    //Create pie or douhnut chart
                    // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
                    pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions)
                })  
                </script>
<canvas id="pieChart" style="height:400px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a great time on google with this problem..

Basically the way other developers solve your problem was creating a plugin which makes all the tooltips show up after the render

I found a fiddle that fixes this problem..

The fiddle is not mine..

> Credits goes to Suhaib Janjua

```js
// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero

Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });

      // turn off normal tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      // turn on tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero


var canvas = $('#myCanvas2').get(0).getContext('2d');
var doughnutChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Success",
      "Failure"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [45, 9],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#1ABC9C",
        "#566573"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#148F77",
        "#273746"
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    // In options, just use the following line to show all the tooltips
    showAllTooltips: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
     <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="350" height="296"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome, but chart.bundle.min.js can't work because AdminLTE is using chart.min.js, i try to use them both but not work, if i'm using only chart.bundle.min the other chart is disappear.  and i use exact example from AdminLTE Example charts, how i solve that

Comment: @GisellAnnisa does this means that you can't refactor your code to work with chart.bundle.min.js because you base on AdminLTE docs?... well I do think that would be a problem if you could also try to understand how admin LTE is trying to show charts. Just so that in the future you don't get confused when either ChartJs or AdminLTE updates. 

I can't really help you out on something that is limiting you. AdminLTE is just using chartJS just like everyone else is. maybe you could try to understand how it works and try to change it to fit your needs. (i will still look for ways to help you)

Answer (score 0):

I use onclick event and bootstrap modal for this issue and  disabled Tooltip.

```
        ,onClick: function(c,i) {
            e = i[0];
            var x_value = this.data.labels[e._index];
            var ID = x_value;
            var Type =1;


                $.ajax({
                            url: 'getsearchresults.asmx/ChartDetayGetir',
                            data: "{ 'ID': '" + ID + "',type:'"+Type+"'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {

                            document.getElementById("modalheader").innerHTML = x_value;

                            document.getElementById("modalbody").innerHTML = data.d;

                            $('#myModal').modal();

                                    },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert('Failure');
                            }
                        });






        }
```

Comment: They are more like, "what if the user don't wanna click those piecharts, how can they now what the Orange Color means?"  so maybe they want to charts always show the tooltip. I search in the charts.js and i can't find how to make tooltip always visible.